# How do I prevent this infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop, unsigned-char

When I run the following code, sometimes it will exit successfully and sometimes it will enter an infinite loop if highestNum is equal to 255. I understand that this happens because of rollover when 255 gets incremented and becomes 0. I understand why this is happening but I would like advice on stopping this. Should I put an if statement at the end to check if i is equal to the max number and then break at the end? this seems like bad style and something that is easy to forget to fix if i increased the size of the variables.

```
    // delete all the files
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i <= highestNum; i++){
        rc = snprintf(formatString, sizeof(formatString), "x%u", i);
        if (rc < 0){
            perror("snprintf in delete");
        }
        rc = unlinkat(directoryFD, formatString, 0);
        if (rc == 0){
            printf("file unlinked\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to pick the right variable for the job. If you know you will never have `highestNum` >= 255 then the current implementation is fine. But if you can ever have `highestNum` >= 255 then you should just pick a different type.

Comment: Use `unsigned short` instead of `unsigned char` for `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Use instead of the type unsigned char the type unsigned int.:)
Otherwise when i is equal to the maximum value for the type that is to 255  (`UCHAR_MAX is equal to 255`) then the next value after increment of i will be again 0 and you will get an infinite loop.

So any value of the variable highestNum that is equal to or greater than `UCHAR_MAX` results in infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wider type (such as `unsigned int`) to do this with a minimal code change. Another option is to use a *different* loop variations, such as a `do..while`:

```
int highestNum = 255;
{
    unsigned char i = 0;
    do {
        printf("%u\n", i);
        ++i;
    } while (i <= highestNum && i != 0);
}
```

This has similar scoping to your `for` loop in that `i` does not "escape" the block it's declared in, and the checking for `i` against zero catches the wrap-around case (something more difficult in a `for` loop as it checks the condition at the *start* of each iteration rather than the end).

Note that there's no check to ensure `highestNumber` is zero or more, so at least *one* file will always be deleted. If you want the capability to specify no files (eg, you would set `highestNumber` to `-1` if *no* files were to be deleted), you could add a simple pre-check:

```
int highestNum = 255;
if (highestNumber >= 0) {
    unsigned char i = 0;
    do {
        printf("%u\n", i);
        ++i;
    } while (i <= highestNum && i != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of avoiding this can be declaring `i` as an `int`, and then casting it to a `char` in the loop where it is used.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= highestNum; i++){
    rc = snprintf(formatString, sizeof(formatString), "x%u", (unsigned char) i);
    if (rc < 0){
        perror("snprintf in delete");
    }
    rc = unlinkat(directoryFD, formatString, 0);
    if (rc == 0){
        printf("file unlinked\n");
    }
}
```